# AADSTS500011: The resource principal named XXXX.api.crm4.dynamics.com was not found in the tenant named XXXX

Tags: azure-active-directory, postman, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I tried to execute the CALL at D365 CRM Online API. I am using Postman.But when I tried to Get new Access Token, I have the following error:

"**AADSTS500011: The resource principal named XXXX.api.crm4.dynamics.com was not found in the tenant named XXXXX. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.**"

Here the steps that I followed:

1. Create new App registration on Azure Active Directory
   [image]
   [image: Grant]
   [image]
   [image]
2. Configure Environment on PostMan
   [image]
3. Configure Authorization
   [image]
4. Click On "Get New Access Token"
5. I have this error
   [image]

How can I solve the issue?

Thanks
Alessandro

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue? We've havening the same issue we can't figure out what it is